# How to extend the long click contextual menu of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-menu

I know you can extend a custom action mode with `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()`  , or you can create your own floating modal menu by `OnCreateContextMenu()` , but both of them are not natural UI for the following usecase.

[image]
This is what you see when you do a long click on EditText.

Is there any way to add some more menu items just next to 'paste' functions? let's say something like pasting a pre-defined phrase?
These functions will be only for my apps.

Comment: Call MainActivity.this.openOptionsMenu(); in Edittext LongClickListener.

Comment: Really? I'm not so sure OptionsMenu will get you a menu like the above screen. It will anchor at bottom at best?